# incorrect syntax in assigning value to a variable

Tags: php

There are 4 users (silver, gold, platinum, admin)
maxrange for silver is 5, gold is 10, platinum is 15 and admin is 20

What is wrong in this?

```
$maxrange = ($data['range'] > 1483200000) ? 20 : ($data['range'] > 1451600000 && $data['range'] < 1483200000) ? 15 : ($data['range'] > 0 ? $web['gold_range'] : $web['silver_range']);
```

silver, gold, platinum works fine but for admin $maxrange variable holds value as 15 whereas it should hold 20

Is there anything incorrect in syntax? Can someone help please...

Also... range is actually a int(255) type in database that shows a date. 1483200001 is 31-12-2016 16:00. How to decode int to date/time?

Comment: Rewrite your lengthy ternary chain into a few `if`/`elseif` blocks. Much easier on the eyes and to get correct.

Comment: I am not a coder :( It was lengthy from beginning. I have modified this statement and made it work as per my desire. I was successful in making three users work silver gold and platinum. Not sure why admin user is not holding correct value. I cannot breakup this lengthy code as I am not a programmer and unaware of proper syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably learn what your code is doing before you start to apply it

```
    if($data['range'] > 1483200000) 
        $maxrange = 20;
    elseif(($data['range'] < 1483200000) && ($data['range'] > 1451600000))
        $maxrange = 15;
    else {
            // If $web['gold_range'] or $web['silver_range'] are empty or not set,
            // this portion will fail/produce an empty result
            $maxrange = ($data['range'] > 0)? $web['gold_range'] : $web['silver_range'];
        }

    echo $maxrange;
```

This by the way, is not an answer so much as it breaks down your code. If you are getting a `$maxrange` of 15 and it's supposed to be 20, then one of two things are likely happening:

1) You have set `$maxrange` already (in a loop or something) and your input doesn't fit any of your conditions so it will retain the last set value of `$maxrange`

2) Your input fits this `(($data['range'] > 1451600000) && ($data['range'] < 1483200000))` condition

Your date is formatting is written:

```
date('d-m-Y H:i','1483200000');
```

You can format your date by checking formatting options on the [php website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data['range']>1483200000)
$maxrange=20;
else{
    if($data['range'] > 1451600000 && $data['range'] < 1483200000)
            $maxrange=15;
        else{
            if($data['range'] > 0)
                $maxrange=$web['gold_range']; 
            else
                $maxrange=$web['silver_range'];
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanx... appreciate a lot !

Answer (score 0):

For converting int val to date

```
$intVal = '1483200001';

$dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($intVal));
```